# Can I track incomplete Scarab locations on the map?

Tags: yokus-island-express

Have been working on activating all the Scarabs in the pinball areas. Was not sure what these were during the initial run through, now there a many incomplete and scattered all over.

Found a nice [map over at IGN](https://www.ign.com/wikis/yokus-island-express/Scarab_Locations_Map), but I will still need to revisit all those location to make sure I actually got everything.

It would be really helpful to have markers on the map (similar to how Treasure Chests and Wickerlings are tracked). Is there a Scarab tracker for the in-game map anywhere?

[image: Scarab Location Map from IGN]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after testing, I found out that Scarab tracking happens automatically when 10 (or less) are left. Woo!